# Apache Hive: converting timestamp from string to timestamp and save it table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, sql-insert

I have a table like this in `hbase`:
`tableExaple (timestamp, timestamp_string, someOtherStuff)`

`timestamp` has the datatype `timestamp`
`timestamp_string` hast the datatype `string` and has the pattern `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'`

Now I would like to read the value from `timestamp_string` convert it with the hive-UDF `unix_timestamp(string date, string pattern)` to a `timestamp` and save this in the same table to the value `timestamp`.

How can I do this?

Stuff like

```
INSERT INTO tableExaple (timestamp) SELECT unix_timestamp(timestamp_string, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') FROM tableExaple;
```

does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `unix_timestamp` likes the millisecond format.  Since `timestamp_string` is of type `string`, you can just split on the `'.'` and grab the date and time.  So if you had `2014-11-11 08:09:10.123`, `split(timestamp_string, '\\.')` will give you `[2014-11-11 08:09:10, 123]`.  You can now reference your array by `[0]` and `[1]`.

**Example:**

```
SELECT otherStuff
    , timestamp
    , unix_timestamp(split(timestamp_string, '\\.')[0], 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') new_time
FROM some_table
```

If you want to include the milliseconds in your `new_time` column, just grab the `[1]`th index from the `split` array (and divide by 1000).